# Information about onsen-ui

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am learning AngularJS and the onsen-ui frameworks. I have a question about what onsen's module offers to the developer when you add it to your own module.

```
angular.module('some-module', ['onsen'])
```

1.- What's it for?

2.- Does it offer any services I can add to my controllers? or it has no sense to type something like this:

```
angular.module('some-module').controller('some-controller',       

    function('onsen'){

        onsen.someFunctionOrAttributte;
    });
```

3.- It has something to do with accesing to the onsen elements inside your controllers by its name defined in the var attribute, or they would be accesible in any case.

Thanks in advance.

Néstor

Comment: The `onsen` module defines all the directives (custom components) so you need to include it in order to use them.

There is a `$onsen` service as well but it's mainly used internally.